# How do I add a c++ library to my c9 project?

Tags: cloud9-ide

I want to add curl and jansson to my c9 c++ project. I can't find any c9 documentation for this task so is this even supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of Cloud9 workspaces like Ubuntu machines that you have sudo access to. They come with a lot of libraries pre-installed, but it shouldn't stop you from installing and using most other libraries.

Since each workspace is uses Ubuntu, installation instructions for Ubuntu should work as-is on Cloud9 workspaces.

Comment: For details or issues, contact support@c9.io